# Solr filter query including NOT and OR

Tags: search, solr, filter, boolean

For a filter query in Solr, I need to include all documents not of a certain type, plus any documents of that type which have a value in a certain field.

I tried this:

```
fq=(-type_id:(A) OR content:(['' TO *]))
```

But it is excluding documents of `type_id` B, C, etc. which have null `content`.  (`type_id` is a `string` field and `content` is `text`.)

I have seen this question: [Complex SOLR query including NOT and OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688910/complex-solr-query-including-not-and-or) and this post about operators: http://robotlibrarian.billdueber.com/2011/12/solr-and-boolean-operators/.  I think the syntax I have should be correct.  Can anyone see my error?

---

Update: I am using the LuceneQParser.  It parses the filter query above as

```
-type_id:A content:['' TO *]
```

It parses the filter query suggested in the comments (`-type_id:A OR (content:[* TO *] AND type_id:A)`) as

```
-type_id:A (+content:[* TO *] +type_id:A)
```

so no results.

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?? type_id not A OR all documents with no content or some content ?

Comment: @Jayendra See the first sentence of my question: no restriction on documents that are not type_id=A; if they are type_id=A, they should have non-null content.  I also tried, for example, `fq=((type_id:(A) AND content:(['' TO *])) OR type_id:(*))`, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you try fq=-type_id:A OR (content:[* TO *] AND type_id:A)

Comment: @Jayendra I tried your suggestion for a filter query; now I get no results.  Please see the query parser info in my updated question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The negation needs a complete set to match against it, so your filter should be:

```
fq=((*:* AND -type_id:A) OR content:(['' TO *]))
```

Comment: Ah, wish this had been posted while I was still at that job!  Can't test it but it makes sense, so thanks!  Accepted.