# How to config Solr to exclude certain documents from search result on any wild card search

Tags: solr

To exclude some documents from the search result, I can use the not in or - negative sign to specify the ids like this through a query.

select/?q=*:*&fq=-id:86+-id:338

But i want to pre configure in solr that on any search the results of certain documents will never show up

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855830/how-to-do-not-in-query-in-solr

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743626/solr-filter-query-including-not-and-or

Answer (score 2):

You can add a parameter list to a definition for a requestHandler that appends a `fq` statement to all requests. [The example from the wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#Configuration) does something similar:

```
<lst name="appends">
  <!-- no matter what other fq are also used, always remove these two documents -->
  <str name="fq">-id:(86 338)</str>
</lst>
```

This fq will then always be appended to the request made.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use following :

```
<lst name="appends">
  <str name="excludeIds">86,338</str>
</lst>
```

I tried and it also gives expected result.